# batch file: using a batch file to read multiple .txt files and assign a value to each

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder that contains multiple .txt files. I would like to be able to make a batch file to read those files and assign a variable to each value (each .txt file only contains one number). I have found scripts to read the individual files, but lack the ability to assign a variable to each of them.

Comment: Examples! Typical filenames, variable-name to which you want to assign the value. How many? Any exceptions?

Comment: i need to scan a folder that contains tickets for archiving jobs, so each folder would contain text files named JOB_*.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how you want to name your variables. I'll assume you want a variable name that matches the job name. For example, if file is named `JOB_123.txt`, then the variable would be named `JOB_123`

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr "^" job_*.txt') do set "%%A=%%B"
```

If the job numbers don't matter, and you simply want an array of values, then:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr "^" job_*.txt^|findstr /n "^"') do set jobCnt=%%A&set "job[%%A]=%%C"
```

This will create variables named `job[1]`, `job[2]`, etc. And `jobCnt` will contain the total number of values.

Comment: is there a way to add up the values of the job variables?

Comment: @user3792076 - Sure. Have a look at the `SET /A` command. For example, `set total+=%%B` within a FOR loop would sum up the total of all of the `%%B` values.

Comment: could you give me specific code? Im sorry for the inconvenice, im just not very experienced with batch files

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
set c=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d ') do (
set /a c+=1
set /p a[!c!]=<"%%a"
)
set a[
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
:: remove variables starting JOB
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set JOB 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\job_*.txt" '
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('type "%%a"') DO (
  IF DEFINED %%~na (ECHO %%~na repeated) ELSE (SET "%%~na=%%b")
 )
)

SET job

GOTO :EOF
```

This job should set up variables named `job_*` containing the data read from each `job_*.txt` file found in the subtree with root at `sourcedir` - I used `u:\sourcedir` which suits my system. You would need to change that to suit yours.